# Why and how display zoom option changes iPhone screen size in points?

Tags: ios, iphone, retina-display, screen-resolution, screen-size

In iPhone, the 6 & 7 series have the display zoom option. If we enable it then the screen size will be changed accordingly in points.

1. In case of iPhone **6, 6s, 7** the screen size will change from 375 × 667 points to 320 × 568 points which is iPhone **5, 5s**'s actual screen size in points.
2. In case of iPhone **6+, 6s+, 7+** the screen size will change from 414 × 736 points to 375 × 667 points which is iPhone **6, 6s, 7**'s actual screen size in points.

Now I'm little bit confused here. As we all know the **Points** is based on coordinates of device's physical screen. Then how the actual screen size of iPhone is changing in **display zoom** option without changing the screen's width and height physically? I mean whats the logic behind this.

Look I may be wrong with the concept of screen size in Points I'm explaining here. In that case, please explain the original concept.

Answer (score 2):

The points are the logical resolution that the OS presents to the applications. It is then mapped onto physical pixels, usually in a 2x resolution, but for example the Plus models do not have enough pixels for a straight translation, so there is some mismatch there already. That mapping is done by the OS automatically.

The zoom options set a lower logical resolution (forcing for example apps to render for a virtual 4-inch screen even though the device has a bigger physical one), making everything appear larger.

Either way, apps do not get to render pixels directly. They output according to virtual points.